# Controller scaffolding is throwing error in VS 2017 preview for ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I am getting error while creating new scaffold item.

[I am adding as shown(click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5V8H.png)

[error (click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGqv8.png)

I have created ApplicationDBContext and added it to configure services

[Content of csproj file(here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NM2mS.png)

Comment: Can you paste the contents of your .csproj file?

Comment: added the contents of .csproj file